# How to generate packets with incrementing lengths with scapy

Tags: linux, networking, scapy

I need to send a sequence of packets from min to max ethernet size to verify
hardware.  Would be best to use scapy since that's the tool of choice for existing
tests.

Is there a way to have scapy to send a sequence of packets of incrementing length?

Using the [x,y] form for length seems to only change header field values, not data length.

`pak=(Ether()/IP(len=[100,101])`

It is possible to create a large pcap file with all the required packets and
read from that, but I was hoping for something more lightweight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like

```py
packets = (Ether()/IP()/Raw(load=b"\x00" * i) for i in range(1000))
sendp(packets)
```

to send packets with a payload from 0 to 1000. The lengths will be computed automatically

Comment: Great.. just what I was looking for.  I did have to make one small change to the load syntax since the "\x00" was adding 4 bytes at a time.  By using (load='0' * i) instead, it works perfectly.  Thanks!

Comment: You're right I forgot the trailing `b`. It should have been b`\x00` haha. Glad I could help